# Convert numbers to English strings

Tags: python, nlp

Websites like http://www.easysurf.cc/cnvert18.htm and http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/conversions/numberstowords.php tries to convert a numerical string into an english strings, but they are giving natural sounding output.

For example, on http://www.easysurf.cc/cnvert18.htm:

```
[in]: 100456
[out]:  one hundred  thousand four hundred fifty-six
```

this website is a little better, http://www.calculator.org/calculate-online/mathematics/text-number.aspx:

```
[in]: 100456
[out]: one hundred thousand, four hundred and fifty-six

[in]: 10123124001
[out]: ten billion, one hundred and twenty-three million, one hundred and twenty-four thousand, one
```

but it breaks at some point:

```
[in]: 10000000001
[out]: ten billion, , , one
```

I've wrote my own version but it involves lots of rules and it caps at one billion, from http://pastebin.com/WwFCjYtt:

```
import codecs

def num2word (num):
  ones = {1:"one",2:"two",3:"three",4:"four",
          5:"five",6:"six",7:"seven",8:"eight",
          9:"nine",0:"zero",10:"ten"}
  teens = {11:"eleven",12:"twelve",13:"thirteen",
           14:"fourteen",15:"fifteen"}
  tens = {2:"twenty",3:"thirty",4:"forty",
          5:"fifty",6:"sixty",7:"seventy",
          8:"eighty",9:"ninety"}
  lens = {3:"hundred",4:"thousand",6:"hundred",7:"million",
          8:"million", 9:"million",10:"billion"#,13:"trillion",11:"googol",
          }

  if num > 999999999:
    return "Number more than 1 billion"

  # Ones
  if num < 11:
    return ones[num]
  # Teens
  if num < 20:
    word = ones[num%10] + "teen" if num > 15 else teens[num]
    return word
  # Tens
  if num > 19 and num < 100:
    word = tens[int(str(num)[0])]
    if str(num)[1] == "0":
      return word
    else:
      word = word + " " + ones[num%10]
      return word

  # First digit for thousands,hundred-thousands.
  if len(str(num)) in lens and len(str(num)) != 3:
    word = ones[int(str(num)[0])] + " " + lens[len(str(num))]
  else:
    word = ""

  # Hundred to Million  
  if num < 1000000:
    # First and Second digit for ten thousands.  
    if len(str(num)) == 5:
      word = num2word(int(str(num)[0:2])) + " thousand"
    # How many hundred-thousand(s).
    if len(str(num)) == 6:
      word = word + " " + num2word(int(str(num)[1:3])) + \
            " " + lens[len(str(num))-2]
    # How many hundred(s)?
    thousand_pt = len(str(num)) - 3
    word = word + " " + ones[int(str(num)[thousand_pt])] + \
            " " + lens[len(str(num))-thousand_pt]
    # Last 2 digits.
    last2 = num2word(int(str(num)[-2:]))
    if last2 != "zero":
      word = word + " and " + last2
    word = word.replace(" zero hundred","")
    return word.strip()

  left, right = '',''  
  # Less than 1 million.
  if num < 100000000:
    left = num2word(int(str(num)[:-6])) + " " + lens[len(str(num))]
    right = num2word(int(str(num)[-6:]))
  # From 1 million to 1 billion.
  if num > 100000000 and num < 1000000000:
    left = num2word(int(str(num)[:3])) +  " " + lens[len(str(num))]
    right = num2word(int(str(num)[-6:]))
  if int(str(num)[-6:]) < 100:
    word = left + " and " + right
  else:  
    word = left + " " + right
  word = word.replace(" zero hundred","").replace(" zero thousand"," thousand")
  return word

print num2word(int(raw_input("Give me a number:\n")))
```

**How can I make the script i've wrote accept `> billion`?**

**Is there any other way to get the same output?**

**Can my code be written in a less verbose way?**

Comment: Consider adding 16,17,18,19 to `teens`. It's one less special case to worry about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more general approach to this problem uses repeated division (i.e. `divmod`) and only hardcodes the special/edge cases necessary.

For example, `divmod(1034393, 1000000) -> (1, 34393)`, so you've effectively found the number of millions and are left with a remainder for further calculations.

Possibly more illustrative example: `divmod(1034393, 1000) -> (1034, 393)` which allows you to take off groups of 3 decimal digits at a time from the right.

In English we tend to group digits in threes, and similar rules apply. This should be parameterized and not hard coded. For example, "303" could be three hundred and three million, three hundred and three thousand, or three hundred and three. The logic should be the same except for the suffix, depending on what place you're in. Edit: looks like this is sort of there due to recursion.

Here is a partial example of the kind of approach I mean, using a generator and operating on integers rather than doing lots of `int(str(i)[..])` everywhere.

```
say_base = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
    'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen',
    'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']

say_tens = ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy',
    'eighty', 'ninety']

def hundreds_i(num):
    hundreds, rest = divmod(num, 100)
    if hundreds:
        yield say_base[hundreds]
        yield ' hundred'
    if 0 < rest < len(say_base):
        yield ' and '
        yield say_base[rest]
    elif rest != 0:
        tens, ones = divmod(rest, 10)
        yield ' and '
        yield say_tens[tens]
        if ones > 0:
            yield '-'
            yield say_base[ones]

assert "".join(hundreds_i(245)) == "two hundred and forty-five"
assert "".join(hundreds_i(999)) == 'nine hundred and ninety-nine'
assert "".join(hundreds_i(200)) == 'two hundred'
```

Comment: This returns "one hundred zero thousand" for 100000, and "one million and zero" for 1000000. It seems not consistent in adding the word "and" either ("one hundred and one million" versus "one hundred one thousand")

Answer (score 4):

There is a module called `num2words` available in python. You should install and import.

```
#Installation:

#if version is python-2
pip install num2words

#if version is python-3
pip3 install num2words

#Usage:

from num2words import num2words

#The following number has 31 digits

print(num2words(9856324785621354789654785239874))

#output: 
nine nonillion, eight hundred and fifty-six octillion, three hundred and twenty-four septillion, seven hundred and eighty-five sextillion, six hundred and twenty-one quintillion, three hundred and fifty-four quadrillion, seven hundred and eighty-nine trillion, six hundred and fifty-four billion, seven hundred and eighty-five million, two hundred and thirty-nine thousand, eight hundred and seventy-four
```

Answer (score 3):

As the currently accepted answer has some issues with "zero", I provide here another answer:

```
def number_to_text(n, *, hyphen="-", joiner="and", comma=","):
    unitNames = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", 
                 "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
                 "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]
    tensNames = ["twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", 
                 "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]
    tripletNames = ["", "thousand"] + [s + "illion" 
                        for s in ["m", "b", "tr", "quadr", "quint", 
                                  "sext", "sept", "oct", "non"]
                    ] + [s + "decillion"
                        for s in ["", "un", "duo", "tre", "quattuor", 
                                  "quin", "sex", "septen", "octo", "novem"]
                    ] + ["vigintillion"]  # add as needed....
                
    def triplets(n):
        for tripletName in tripletNames:
            num = n % 1000
            n //= 1000
            if num == 0:
                continue
            hundreds = num // 100
            num %= 100
            tens =  num // 10 if num > 19 else 0
            num -= tens * 10
            yield ((unitNames[hundreds-1] + " hundred " if hundreds else "")
                + (joiner + " " if joiner and (n or hundreds) and (tens or num) else "") 
                + (tensNames[tens-2] + (hyphen if num else " ") if tens else "")
                + (unitNames[num-1] + " " if num else "")
                + tripletName).strip()
            if n == 0:
                return
        raise ValueError("number too large for this converter")

    return (comma + " ").join(reversed(list(triplets(n)))) if n else "zero"
```

Example call:

```
print(number_to_text(1234567890123456789, hyphen="-", joiner="and", comma=","))
```

Output:

> one quintillion, two hundred and thirty-four quadrillion, five hundred and sixty-seven trillion, eight hundred and ninety billion, one hundred and twenty-three million, four hundred and fifty-six thousand, seven hundred and eighty-nine

If you prefer no commas or no "and", then pass empty strings for the corresponding options:

```
print(number_to_text(101000001, hyphen="-", joiner="", comma=""))
```

> one hundred one million one

NB: this uses the [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales). If you need the long scale, then update the list `tripletNames` accordingly.